# counting how many time the order of two consecutive number in a file are reversed in a second file in BASH

Tags: algorithm, bash, awk

I got the following problem:

Given 2 files of N numbers like

file1.dat: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

file2.dat: 2,5,4,7,6,9,8,1,0,3

The file2.dat is actually just a shuffled version of the first one.
I want to know how many time the order of two consecutive numbers in the first file has changed in the second (that contain the same numbers). For exemple, in the file one we start looking for 1 and 2, in the second file 2 come before the 1, so there was a change of the order; in the first file there is 9 and then 0 and also in the second file this order is maintained because 9 come before 0.

The actual data that I'm using are roughly composed of 26000 numbers and they are all distinct.

I thought of somenthing like:

```
for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
      for(k=0 ; k<N; k++)
        if(B[j]==A[i] && B[k]==A[i+1] && k < j )
        count++

     print("The number of inversion is: %d\n",count)
```

But I don't know how to write it in awk (I wrote a little C program but it takes more than 5 hours to give me the answer) and I don't know if something like could give me a result in a resonable time.

Comment: *Why* do you want to solve this is Bash or AWK? Are you somehow assuming the same solution in a scripting language will run faster than in C?

Comment: That s what I hope, and also because they are the only two languages that I know.. If C fail I hope that BASH or AWK could do it faster..

Comment: do you only care about those neighbor pairs? e.g. in file1 1..4 in file2 4..1, should this also be counted or not? btw, can you give the correct answer/result of your file1,file2 (10 numbers) example?

Comment: If your C program took 5 hours to run then the issue is your algorithm rather than the tool you're programming in and any implementation of that algorithm in bash or awk will run slower than it did in C so this may not be the best forum for advice - you need an algorithm, not tool.

Comment: and are numbers in the file1 in your real world also followed the rule ..i-1, i, i+1.. ? or ..i-n, i, i+n...?

Comment: @Kent the result is 3 inversions. The numbers in the real dataset aren't sorted like in this example in the file1.dat..

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti why 3? 1-2, 3-4, 4-5, 6-7,8-9  those pairs are inverted. so in total 5. am I right?

Comment: in the first there are 1-2 in the second file 2 comes before 1, so 1 inversion; then 2-3 in the first file, in the second file 2 comes before 3, so still 1 inversion; then 3-4 in the first file, in the second 4 comes before 3, so we are at 2 inversions etc etc...

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti yes, that's why I said we have 5 inversions in total, not 3. anyway, I am posting my answer, you will see in 2 mins

Comment: @Kent Sorry I was looking on another file... yes you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope your two files obey the certain rules:

- same amount of distinct number,
- both files have single line

I didn't do those format checking. see my solution:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{n=NF;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)o[i]=$i;next;}
        {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)v[$i]=i}
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) t+=v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0;
                print "inversions:",t;
        }' file1 file2
```

test:

```
kent$  head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

==> file2 <==
2,5,4,7,6,9,8,1,0,3


kent$  awk -F, 'FNR==NR{n=NF;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)o[i]=$i;next;}
        {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)v[$i]=i}
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) t+=v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0;
                print "inversions:",t;
        }' file1 file2
inversions: 5
```

If you want to print some debug info, say, print inversion pairs as well, see this:

```
kent$  awk -F, 'FNR==NR{n=NF;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)o[i]=$i;next;}
        {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)v[$i]=i}
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) {

        if(v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]){
                print "inversion pair foud:"o[i],o[i+1]
                t++;
        }
        }
                print "inversions:",t;
        }' file1 file2

inversion pair foud:1 2
inversion pair foud:3 4
inversion pair foud:4 5
inversion pair foud:6 7
inversion pair foud:8 9
inversions: 5
```

if you want some other information e.g. original index/order, changed order, they are also easy to be added.

hope it helps.

**EDIT**

if your data files are in single-column format. try this:

```
 awk -F, 'FNR==NR{o[NR]=$0;next;}{v[$0]=FNR;n=FNR}
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) t+=v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0;
                print "invertions:",t;
        }' file1 file2
```

test screencast. just for testing my just written recording script ;)

[image]

Comment: Oops, foud should be found...typo sorry... I will fix it if the answer is needed to be edited...

Comment: I'm trying to run the script but it doesn't work. Maybe because my original files are one column file?

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti you could open it in vim and type `:%s/\n/,/g` oh, maybe you have to remove the tailing comma. anyway, it is also easy to change my awk script to fit your format single line -> single column. shall I do it?

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti I think a new question is better.. it happened 1 month ago, I forgot what was going on, I have to read all questions, answers, and comments....

Comment: Ok I ll make a new question

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti just curious how come this answer is turned into "unaccepted"? didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, probably an admin turned it "uncettable" beacause I edited the question, and the actual answer do not answer at the edit. I m writing a new question, then I'll erase the editing and then reapprove your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already have an accepted clean answer.

Just sharing:

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat stack.sh 
VALUE1=$1
VALUE2=$2
for POS in `sed 's/,/ /g' file1.dat`
do
((COUNT++))
if [[ $VALUE1 == $POS ]] ; then
    VAL1_POS=$COUNT
fi

if [[ $VALUE2 == $POS ]] ; then
        VAL2_POS=$COUNT
fi
done


for MATCH in `sed 's/,/ /g' file2.dat`
do
((COUNT2++))
if [[ $VALUE1 == $MATCH ]] ; then
        VAL1_POS2=$COUNT2
fi
if [[ $VALUE2 == $MATCH ]] ; then
        VAL2_POS2=$COUNT2
fi
done

if [[ $VAL1_POS -gt $VAL2_POS ]] ; then
    P1=1
fi
if [[ $VAL1_POS2 -gt $VAL2_POS2 ]] ; then
    P2=1
fi

if [[ $VAL1_POS -lt $VAL2_POS ]] ; then
    P1=2
fi
if [[ $VAL1_POS2 -lt $VAL2_POS2 ]] ; then
    P2=2
fi

if [[ $VAL1_POS -eq $VAL2_POS ]] ; then
    P1=3
fi
if [[ $VAL1_POS2 -eq $VAL2_POS2 ]] ; then
    P2=3
fi

if [[ $P1 == $P2 ]]; then
    echo "No order change"
else
    echo "Order changed"
fi
```

How to execute the script:

I am assuming following:

- Both file have exactly same numbers in same order.
- You will not give non existing number (not existing in `file*.dat`) as input to the script

> ```
> sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash stack.sh 5 7
> No order change
> sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash stack.sh 4 5
> Order changed
> sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash stack.sh 9 0
> No order change
> sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ bash stack.sh 1 2
> Order changed
> ```