# How to write a complete awk script

Tags: bash, awk

I've the following situation:

I have a file of 1 column data containg only nubmbers. Let's call it `file.dat` .

Then I've to shuffle this file, and for doing it I write in the terminal the following code `shufl file1.dat > shuffle.dat`. Then I want to count how many times the order of two consecutive number from `file1.dat` have been modified in the `shuffle.dat`. I used the code

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{o[NR]=$0;next;}{v[$0]=FNR;n=FNR}
    END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) t+=v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0;
            print t;
    }' file.dat shuffle.dat
```

I must repeat this operations 10,000 times and collect the results in the file `result.dat`. Obviously doing it by terminal is not thinkable for time reasons. It's possible to write an awk script to make it repeat 10,000 times the operations and write the results in the output file `result.dat`? If yes how and how I can run the script by terminal?

Comment: Are the numbers in `file.dat` unique? I would have thought you could write a single script that would run once to work out the number of inversions.

Comment: yep they are. for the inversion I've used the folliwing answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295399/counting-how-many-time-the-order-of-two-consecutive-number-in-a-file-are-reverse)

Comment: Aha, now I understand your question :-) will answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple bash script will achieve this:

```
echo 'FNR==NR{o[NR]=$0;next;}{v[$0]=FNR;n=FNR}
     END{for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) t+=v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0;
     print t;
     }' > script.awk

touch result.dat

for i in {1..10000}; do
    echo 'shuffling file...'
    shuf file.dat > shuf.dat
    echo 'counting inversions...'
    awk -F, -f script.awk file.dat shuf.dat >> result.dat
done
```

Comment: If you save it in a text editor (e.g. as `filename`) and add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning, then you can make the script executable (`chmod +x filename`) and execute it on the command line (`./filename`). [See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting#Scripting) for more details.