# counting how many time the order of two consecutive number in a two column files are reversed

Tags: bash, awk

Given 2 files of N numbers like

file1

```
1 0.001
2 0.002
3 0.002
4 0.005
5 0.007
6 0.008
7 0.008
8 0.009
9 0.0010
0 0.011
```

and the file2 is just a shuffled version of file1:

```
0 0.011
8 0.009
7 0.008
3 0.002
5 0.007
9 0.0010
1 0.001
4 0.005
2 0.002
6 0.008
```

I would like to count the order of two consecutive number but in this case, if in the second column of file1.dat there are two consecutive number that are the same ( as for the case of 2-3 and 6-7 ) I would like that we count directly the inversion as 0.5, without looking into file2.dat. In this case the result would be 4 inversions. A similar question (and answer) was made on [counting how many time the order of two consecutive number in a file are reversed in a second file in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295399/counting-how-many-time-the-order-of-two-consecutive-number-in-a-file-are-reverse/14296306#comment20675280_14296306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did for two cases, pick one you need:

**this is counting 0.5 or 1 case** result =4

```
kent$  awk  'FNR==NR{o[NR]=$1;next;}{v[$1]=FNR;m[$1]=$2;n=FNR}                               
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) { t+=m[o[i]]==m[o[i+1]]?0.5:v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]]?1:0};                                                                                        
                print "invertions:"t;    
        }' f1 f2
invertions:4
```

**this is add extra 0.5 case** result=6

```
kent$  awk  'FNR==NR{o[NR]=$1;next;}{v[$1]=FNR;m[$1]=$2;n=FNR}
        END{ for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++) {t1+=(v[o[i]]>v[o[i+1]])?1:0; t2+=m[o[i]]==m[o[i+1]]?0.5:0};
                print "invertions:"t1+t2;
        }' f1 f2
invertions:6
```

Comment: the result should be 4, the script give 6 invertions. 2 and 3 have the same value in the second column (so 0.5), 4 and 5 are inversed (so +1), 6 and 7 have same value in the second column ( so +0.5), 7 and 8 are inversed (+1) and 9 and 0 are inversed (+1). total number of inversions 4

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti I noticed that too, I updated answer. now you can pick the right one from my two examples